# É possível identificar quais programas aberto utiliza o BDE para conexão? Como faço?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Preciso saber, de uma lista de programas abertos quais se utilizam do BDE para acesso a banco de dados, então quero saber se é possível e como faço.

Att

Luiz

Comment: Uma forma de fazer isso é listar as dll's que o processo usa, mas se o processo ainda não tiver carregado a dll, seria um falso negativo, pois ele não apareceria na lista, seria um problema pra você?

Comment: Não é necessário listar, preciso saber se tem algum programa utilizando-se do acesso a dados com o BDE.
Estou realizando os testes com dbiInit, só que ele se informa se bde está instalado.

Comment: Desculpe-me, o que eu quis dizer é, iterar os módulos carregados (DLL's) e verificar se existe a dll do BDE carregada pelo processo.

Comment: Não acredito que haja outra forma de determinar se o BDE está sendo utilizado, mas a solução, como eu falei, possui essa exceção, quando um processo ainda não carregou a dll, ele não seria considerado um utilizador do BDE

Comment: Se mesmo com a deficiência descrita acima, a solução resolver seu problema, posso codificar uma função que detecta a presença da dll do BDE em um processo, essa função poderia retornar uma lista de PID's, os valores seriam os processos utilizadores do BDE

Comment: @EProgrammerNotFound, entendi! Que tipo de recurso eu preciso para fazer, qual DLL que tenho que buscar para saber se está sendo utilizada para que solicite o encerramento da aplicação?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma forma de fazer isso é listar as `dll`'s que o processo está utilizando, mas se o processo ainda não carregou a `dll` que você estiver procurando, esse processo não aparecerá na lista, segue função para detectar a presença de `dll`'s nos processos.

```
uses TlHelp32;

TCardinalArray = array of Cardinal;
ECanContinue = class(Exception);

function EnumerateProcessesThatHasLoadedAModule(const AModuleName: String; IncludeCurrentProcess: Boolean = False): TCardinalArray; forward;
```

- A função espera como primeiro argumento o nome do módulo.
- O segundo parâmetro especifica se você deseja incluir o próprio    processo na lista de processos a serem verificados, por padrão o valor    é falso, ou seja, o processo atual não será considerado.
- A função retorna uma lista com os PID's que possuem o módulo que você    passou no primeiro argumento.

---

```
function EnumerateProcessesThatHasLoadedAModule(
  const AModuleName: String;
  IncludeCurrentProcess: Boolean = False): TCardinalArray;
var
  ProcessList: array [0..1023] of DWORD;
  I, ProcessCount: Integer;
  BytesReturnedInProcessList: DWORD;
  CurrentProcessID: Cardinal;
  UpperModule: String;
  IsModulePresent: Boolean;

  function IsModuleDetected(const TargetModuleName: String; PID: DWORD): Boolean;
  var
    ModuleEntry32: TModuleEntry32;
    RetVal, ErrorCode: Cardinal;
    HasModule: Boolean;
    StrModuleName: String;
  begin
    Result:= False;
    repeat
      RetVal:= CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, PID);

      ErrorCode := ERROR_SUCCESS;
      if RetVal = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
      begin
        ErrorCode:= GetLastError;
        if ErrorCode <> ERROR_BAD_LENGTH then
        begin
          if (ErrorCode = ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED) or (ErrorCode = ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY) then
            raise ECanContinue.Create(SysErrorMessage(ErrorCode))
          else
            RaiseLastOSError;
        end;
      end;
    until ErrorCode <> ERROR_BAD_LENGTH;

    try
      ModuleEntry32.dwSize := SizeOf(ModuleEntry32);
      HasModule:= Integer(Module32First(RetVal, ModuleEntry32)) <> 0;

      while HasModule do
      begin
        StrModuleName := ModuleEntry32.szModule;
        Result:= UpperCase(StrModuleName) = TargetModuleName;

        if Result  then
          Break
        else
          HasModule:= Integer(Module32Next(RetVal, ModuleEntry32)) <> 0;
      end;
    finally
      CloseHandle(RetVal);
    end;
  end;

begin
  SetLength(Result, 0);
  CurrentProcessID:= GetCurrentProcessId;
  UpperModule:= UpperCase(AModuleName);
  if EnumProcesses(@ProcessList, 1024, BytesReturnedInProcessList) then
  begin
    ProcessCount:= BytesReturnedInProcessList div SizeOf(DWORD);
    for I:= 0 to ProcessCount-1 do
    begin
      if (ConsiderCurrentProcess or (CurrentProcessID <> ProcessList[I])) and  
         //Ignore Idle 'Fake' Process...
         (ProcessList[I] <> 0 )  then
      begin
        try
          IsModulePresent:= IsModuleDetected(UpperModule, ProcessList[I]);

          //FROM MSDN:
          (*
             If the specified process is the Idle process or one of the CSRSS processes,
             this function fails and the last error code is ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED because their access restrictions
             prevent user-level code from opening them.
          *)
        except
          on E: ECanContinue do
            IsModulePresent := False;
          else
            raise;
        end;

        if IsModulePresent then
        begin
          SetLength(Result, Length(Result) + 1);
          Result[Length(Result) -1] := ProcessList[I];
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end
  else
    RaiseLastOSError;
end;
```

A chamada da função seria assim:

```
var PIDs: TCardinalArray;
begin
  PIDs:= EnumerateProcessesThatHasLoadedAModule('IDAPI32.DLL');
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!!!!

Comment: @LuizVichiatto Por nada, IDAPI32.dll é uma das dll's do BDE, acredito que se você utilizar ela sempre vai dar certo, eu utilizei o process explorer da microsoft pra detectar essa dll

Comment: @LuizVichiatto Não testei essa função em 64 bits.

Comment: esquenta não que testo.... estou com uma "pá" de equipamentos para testar (4) xp, 7, 8 e 10... ufa quero ver se vai funcionar.... valeu colega, amanhã te conto como foram os primeiros testes. []s